# pop up message without using alert()

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online

I have created warning messages using alert but it is showing site url also,so
I need to create warning message without using alert in java script

Comment: Javascript alert wouldn't normally show the url, what is the code you are using?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use SP.UI.ModalDialog for this.

Here is the code more or less used in the quicklaunch.js that you could use:

```
var DialogReturnCode = {
    "OK" : true,
    "Cancel" : false 
};

function DismissDlgWithCode(retCode) {
    var dlg = typeof window.top.g_childDialog != "undefined" ? window.top.g_childDialog : undefined;

    if (Boolean(dlg)) {
        dlg.close(retCode);
    }
}
function LaunchMessageDialogCore(dlgTitle, msg, isConfirmationDlg, dlgHandler) {
    var innerHtmlStr = "<div>{0}</div><div class='ms-dnd-dlg-buttonDiv'><button id='js-navedit-OKBtnDismissDlg' onclick='DismissDlgWithCode(DialogReturnCode.OK)'>{1}</button>";

    if (isConfirmationDlg == true) {
        innerHtmlStr += "<button id='js-navedit-CancelBtnDismissDlg' onclick='DismissDlgWithCode(DialogReturnCode.Cancel)'>{2}</button>";
    }
    innerHtmlStr += "</div>";
    var divElem = document.createElement("DIV");

    divElem.innerHTML = String.format(innerHtmlStr, msg, Strings.STS.L_OkButtonCaption, Strings.STS.L_CancelButtonCaption);
    var dopt = {
        html: divElem,
        title: dlgTitle,
        dialogReturnValueCallback: dlgHandler
    };
    var dlg = EnsureScriptParams("SP.UI.Dialog.js", "SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog", dopt);

    if (!isConfirmationDlg == false) {
        var okButton = document.getElementById('js-navedit-OKBtnDismissDlg');

        if (Boolean(okButton))
            okButton.focus();
    }
}
function LaunchMessageDialog(dlgTitle, msg, dlgHandler) {
    LaunchMessageDialogCore(dlgTitle, msg, false, dlgHandler);
}
function LaunchConfirmDialog(dlgTitle, msg, dlgHandler) {
    LaunchMessageDialogCore(dlgTitle, msg, true, dlgHandler);
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
LaunchConfirmDialog("Dialog Title","Your warning",function(result){ console.log(result); });

LaunchMessageDialog("Dialog Title","Your warning",function(result){ console.log(result); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try "window.confirm()"

```
var r = confirm("Press a button");
if (r == true) {
x = "You pressed OK!";
} else {
x = "You pressed Cancel!";
}
```

source http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom jQuery dialog in which you can customize title of popup.

Syntax and demo  can be found [here](http://runnable.com/UfNMPnKMU1ZgAACQ/how-to-create-custom-jquery-alert-confirm-and-prompt-dialogs).